# ViewPager with ListView and EditTexts inside. Focusability issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have implemented UI screen based on columns. `ViewPager` contains `Fragments`, which also contain `ListView`s with `EditText` fields. unfortunately, those `EditText` fields do not get focus appropriately.

Before putting `Fragment`s with `ListView`s inside of ViewPager, I have experienced issue with `EditText`s, which was solved by specifying `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in activity manifest.

But new issue appeared when I started to use multicolumn ViewPager. EditText fields are getting focus only in **first** visible `Page` of `ViewPager`. If I slightly move unfocusable page from second, to first position, it gains focus as should, and I can now again enter values into `EditText` Fields. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, in first column I can enter values into EditText. But I cannot do the same with the second column, unless I move it to first position like this.

[image]

Do you guys have any ideas how to find solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it but maybe you can try android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in the layout. So the listView itself shouldn't be focusable anymore but the editText should be.

Comment: focusability properties will apply recursively to all child views of specified layout. So no, it will make everything even worse (will remove focus from all views in layout) :(